# Rows don't follow specific pattern and maybe different

Tags: java, excel, matlab

I have data in a text document with some rows having more parameters (in no particular order) than other rows. There are about 90 parameters in the data.

e.g
First 100 lines have 4 parameters like:

> {"A":1.675,"B":21.8,"C":34,"D":63}

Now lines 150 - 200 have 6 parameters like:

> {"A":1.675,"B":21.8,"C":34,"D":63,"E":34,"F":87}

Then lines 200-250 are again like first 100 likes
and then somewhere in between lines 350-400 again have 6 parameters but in a different format like:

> {"A":1.675,"B":21.8,"C":34,"F":63,"E":34,"D":87}

I want the data to be processed and appear like:

[image]

This is how the data looks:

> ```
> {"total_gas":0.0,"hook_load":9.7,"mud_flow_in":0.0,"pump_spm_total":0.0,"svy_azimuth":171.8872648725456,"pit_volume_8":0.0,"gain_loss":0.3,"pit_volume_7":0.0,"pit_volume_6":0.0,"block_height":114.9,"pit_volume_5":0.0,"pit_volume_4":0.0,"pit_volume_3":0.0,"pit_volume_2":0.0,"drill_hardness":0.0,"pit_volume_1":0.0,"strks_pump_3":0.0,"weight_on_bit":0.0,"strks_pump_1":0.0,"strks_pump_2":0.0,"standpipe_pressure":0.0,"mud_flow_out":0.0,"state":"InSlips","svy_depth":0.0,"mud_volume":484.1,"rotary_rpm":0.0,"strks_total":0.0,"hole_depth":0.0,"pump_spm_3":0.0,"pump_spm_2":0.0,"rop_fast":0.0,"pump_spm_1":0.0,"mud_temp_in":0.0,"svy_inclination":229.18301983006077,"mud_temp_out":0.0,"rotary_torque":0.006,"gamma_ray":0.0,"diff_press":0.0,"bit_depth":0.0,"rop_average":0.0}~{}
> ```

I want the program to read each line and place it in the appropriate column. I know java, excel and matlab only.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, if you have not done so already please read over how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What program? Without providing some indication that you have a programming coding problem (e.g. some code that is not working) as opposed to appearing to be asking for a code writing service, then you are very likely to get adverse responses.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your file is written in [json](/questions/tagged/json) format (see [`json` info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info) for more information).

You can parse the file using matlab's [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html):

```
fid = fopen('/path/to/file');
line = fgetl(fid);
out = struct();
while ischar(line)
    res = regexp(line, '\{([^\}]+)\}','tokens','once');  %// remove {} from line
    if isempty(res)
       continue;  %// empty line?
    end
    res2 = regexp(res{1},'"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*([^,]+),?', 'tokens');  %// get the key-value pairs
    for ii=1:numel(res2)
        if isfield(out, res2{ii}{1})
           out.(res2{ii}{1}){end+1} = str2double(res2{ii}{2});
        else
           out.(res2{ii}{1}) = {str2double(res2{ii}{2})};
        end
    end
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

You should have all the data is the struct `out` with the fields corresponding to the column names.